# Laravel Rate Limiter dont work on production (Digitalocean)

Tags: php, laravel, digital-ocean

I have a problem, in my **Laravel application I use Rate Limiter**, which normally **works on localhost** it throws error 429 normally, but after uploading to **digitalocean** it doesn't work as if it doesn't exist at all  and I can spam requets endlessly.
Do you know what to do ? Thanks

Otherwise I am using **nginx** and **CACHE_DRIVER=memcached** on hosting and on localhost apache and CACHE_DRIVER=file.

php -v 7.4

Laravel -v 7.30


I hope I'm not missing anything here.

web.php

```
Route::middleware('throttle:1,5')->group(function () {
  Route::post('/', 'LandingPageController@store')->name('index.store')->middleware(ProtectAgainstSpam::class);
});
```

I also used my own middleware **(config in RouteServiceProdiver.php)**, which again works on localhost but not on hosting

```
Route::middleware('throttle:test')->group(function () {
  Route::post('/', 'LandingPageController@store')->name('index.store')->middleware(ProtectAgainstSpam::class);
});
```

Middleware  (config in RouteServiceProdiver.php)

```
protected function configureRateLimiter()
    {
        RateLimiter::for('test', function (Request $request){
            return Limit::perMinute(1);
        });
    }
```

Comment: have you tried `php artisan optimize:clear` or `php artisan config:clear` on prod server, to caching delete?

Comment: Yes i tried :/ and still nothin

Comment: How you generate "spam requests endlessly" ? An hypotesis can be that there is a browser cache.. If you echo a timestamp in page, what do you see?

Comment: I have a contact form on the main page, where I have a rate limiter on the POST method, where I have a limited POST method (1 post per minute), on the hosting I can send it as many times as I want, so this is what i mean i can spam it endlessly
What do u mean echo timestamp ? u mean now()->timestamp; ? Sorry dont know what u mean

Comment: Ah ok ..sorry it was a POST. Any browser cache loading.

Answer (score 0):

Rate limiter use RateLimiter.php class that use cache. Probably permissions issue deny hits writing *on remote host*.

Search this code in `Illuminate\Cache\RateLimiter`:

```
public function hit($key, $decaySeconds = 60)
    {
        $key = $this->cleanRateLimiterKey($key);

        $this->cache->add(
            $key.':timer', $this->availableAt($decaySeconds), $decaySeconds
        );

        $added = $this->cache->add($key, 0, $decaySeconds);

        $hits = (int) $this->cache->increment($key);



        // log $hits here 
        Log::info('Throttling hits: '.$hits);



        if (! $added && $hits == 1) {
            $this->cache->put($key, 1, $decaySeconds);
        }

        return $hits;
    }
```

- Add temporarly something like this:

`Log::info('Throttling hits: '.$hits);`

under `$hits` variable definition

- in remote `.env` set **temporarly** APP_DEBUG to `true`
- upload on remote host
- spamming it endlessly :)
- check laravel.log

In this manner you can analyze if the issue is cache writing.

Comment: I did everything you wrote, but laravel.log is empty :// It seems to be completely ignoring

Comment: It looks like when I change CACHE_DRIVER to file it works, but why it doesn't work with memcached ?

Comment: Because probably some configuration issue into `config/cache.php` . What about `php artisan tinker`  and `config('cache.stores.memcached');` ?  -----   compare outputs of localhost configuration with remote host config.

Comment: `Command "tinker" is not defined.`
And where should i use `config('cache.stores.memcached');` ?

Comment: From CLI go to the root application.
Laravel have it installed by default: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/artisan#tinker   ---  when inside it shows a commands prompt..

Comment: Do you have `"laravel/tinker": "^2.0",` in `composer.json` ? (If you are using a docker container you have to run it inside the container).